# Callback from AsyncTask class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, asynccallback

I have **APIHelper** class, whose static methods asynchronously make request to server, receive json string, parse and return Object or ArrayList:

```
    ...
public static ArrayList<Item> getItemsInCategory(int id_category) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, JSONException {
        DoRequest doRequest = new DoRequest();
        String jsonString = doRequest.execute(API_PATH + PRODUCT_SEARCH + CATEGORY_ID + id_category).get();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("products");
        return Item.fromJson(jsonArray);
        }
public static Item getItem(int id_item) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, JSONException {
        DoRequest doRequest = new DoRequest();
        String jsonString = doRequest.execute(API_PATH + PRODUCT_GET_INFO + id_item).get();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        return Item.fromJson(jsonObject);
        }
    ...
```

Now I want to make methods without calling **get()** method from AsyncTask class **DoRequest**.

My **DoRequest** class:

```
public class DoRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ResultListener mResultListener;

    public abstract interface ResultListener{
        Object onResultAvailable(String result) throws JSONException;
    }

    DoRequest(ResultListener resultListener){
        mResultListener = resultListener;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... URL) {
        ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();
        String jsonStr = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(URL[0]);
        return jsonStr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            mResultListener.onResultAvailable(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Help me change my methods in APIHelper class that they return values ​​after callback from DoRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an event bus like otto to have the async task publish an event to the event bus once in onPostExecute and then have the whoever the Helper class is returning its results to, listen to the event on the bus and then handle the callback there.

```
http://square.github.io/otto/
```

An example of using this would be:

First you are going to have to use a custom post method to be able to post to threads from the background.

```
public class MainThreadBus extends Bus {
    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override public void post(final Object event) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            super.post(event);
        } else {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    post(event);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now that we have that set up, inside of the class that calls the helper class we create a register on the bus and call the helper method:

```
class someClass(){
    ///some stuff
    public void performRestCall(int id_category){
    bus.register(this);
    ApiHelper.getItemsInCategory(id_category);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void restCallCompleted(GetCategoryEvent e){
    ArrayList<Item> list = e.getList();
    //do whatever else you need to
    bus.unRegister(this);
    }
}
```

Now in the asyncTask onPostExecute we perform all the work we were doing after the asyncTask finished and tell everyone on the bus that this event has completed. We pass the list in the object instead of return it from a method.:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        bus.register(this);
        try {
             JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
             bus.post(new GetCategoryEvent( Item.fromJson(jsonObject));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Your solution will end up being something along these lines.

Comment: Please write an example.

Comment: @user3284037. I wrote a quick little example, this should help explain enough how you use it and how you can actually use it in a class.

Comment: keep in mind that when you are using @Subscribe annotation, make sure you import the otto annotation and not the one for the google bus. This is a very easy mistake to make with IDEs trying to auto import your dependencies.